# View a range of bash history

Tags: bash, command-history

The `history` command lists out all the history for the current session. Like:

```
1 ls 
2 cd /root
3 mkdir something
4 cd something
5 touch afile
6 ls
7 cd ..
8 rm something/afile
9 cd ..
10 ls
11 history
```

In order to search items of interest, I can pipe `history` with `grep` like

```
history | grep ls
1 ls
6 ls
10 ls
```

I can also view last 3 commands like:

```
history 3
11 history
12 history | grep ls
13 history 3
```

But how do I get a specific range of history? For example something like:

```
history range 4 7
4 cd something
5 touch afile
6 ls
7 cd ..
```

Comment: You could list the last `x` commands then pipe to `head`.

Comment: @Bratchley: For that I'd have to know how many last commands to go to. Consider this, my `history | grep something` shows results of commands numbered `123 234 345` in history and I may not know the number of last command executed (`history` in this case). My last command could be numbered 400, 500 or whatever. So first I have to check that number, figure out the difference, list the last `x` commands and then pipe to `head`

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Instead of `history`, you can use [`fc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-History-Builtins-1), which allow you select range:

```
fc -l 4 7
```

Comment: It even accepts negative numbers to count from the end, like `fc -l -16 -10`.

Comment: hmm, wonder why we need a whole new command instead of just arguments to the actual command...

Answer (score 20):

If you **must** use history command, pipe it through sed or awk:

```
history | sed -n '10,20p'

history | awk 'NR >= 10 && NR <= 20'
```

Otherwise cuonglm's answer is better option.

Comment: @questionto42standswithUkraine I've deleted my comment which didn't serve much purpose, but the `15` and `25` in this pipeline should be preceded by a dash. Since they aren't, `tail` and `head` assume they are files they should be reading from, hence the error message

Comment: @questionto42standswithUkraine I'm honestly not convinced that head+tail has any advantage over `sed -n "${start},${end}p"`. If you are, I invite you to add an answer. Otherwise I'll think about adding one but I won't promise anything

Comment: @questionto42standswithUkraine I don't want to post an answer, please stop trying to convince me. Just post the damn answer yourself

Answer (score 3):

Using history with a **grep on the line numbers** around the command I'm looking for works best for me.

For instance I'm looking for what I did around `ping mybox`, more or less 20 lines.

`$ history | grep "ping mybox"
20325  ping mybox`

That's line `20325` so I just have to grep the lines starting by a number in the `[20320..20339]` range.

`$ history | grep ^203[2-3][0-9]`

Comment: (1) You say “more or less 20”, but your example shows −5 and +14.   (2) This doesn’t work for me, because history numbers seem to have leading spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that uses the history command with a parameter.

*Credits go to [this user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/139867/aaron) who did not want to make his now deleted comment an answer. I am taking over since I think that the now deleted comment should be an answer on its own.*

##### Most used

```
history | tail -5
```

gives you the last 5 lines. Which should be all you need in everyday programming, change to the lines you need of course. I am using this by heart from the start, easy to remember.

##### Further

```
history | head -5
```

gives you the first 5 lines,

```
history | tail -10 | head -5
```

gives you the second last 5 lines

```
history | head -10 | tail -5
```

the lines 7 to 11. You need

```
history | head -8 | tail -5
```

to get the second 5 lines, meaning 6 to 10, strange, but no big issue to always add +2 on the head in such cases and you do not need the head of the history anyway or a chosen slice of it if you just want to shrink the full history down to the normally younger commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use 'history', this is a more correct sed-based version, for history lines 4-7:

```
history | sed '/^4 /,/^7 /!d;/^7 /q'
```

This captures the original poster's intention to print the nth lines of history, not the nth lines of output of the history command.  Almost all of the time the two will not be the same. For example, the numbers that the poster cares about in this history output:

```
... 20 preceding lines.
12134 ls dataDir
12135 ls myDir
12136 ls something
... some more lines
```

are 12134,12135,12136, and not 21,22,23, and the sed command should capture that, in this case something like this:

```
history | sed '/^12134 /,/^12135 /!d;/^12135 /q'
```

The specific format for the numbers:

```
'/^n[space]/'
```

captures the intention that the number is at the beginning of the line, and that it is followed by a space. (As I look at this I think the space is unnecessary, but it makes me feel better, ha.)

And yes, as @G.Gabunia says above, fc is easier

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want the range 4 to 7:

```
history  4 | head -n 3
```

In this method, you can generally get history from *n* to *m* with:

```
history n | head -n m-n
```

Note that the `head` command is literally **`head -n`** followed by a number,
as shown in the first command.

Comment: (1) No, `history 4` gives the most recent four commands, not everything starting at command #4.  (2) No, to get thing # _n_ through thing # _m_, you need to grab _m_ − _n_ **+ 1** things. … … … … … … Besides, all of this has been covered already.